# Bash sort row with positional key

Tags: bash, shell

I have a positional file formatted like this :

```
XXXXXXXXXXXYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
```

X is my key 11 length and I want to sort this file with key constraint.

X it is an String Type which could have values like that:

```
FJUYHGRESJFYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
ZNXKDDYHDNKYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `sort`:

```
sort -k 1.1,1.11 input.txt
```

- sort by column `1`, range from position `1st~11th`.